# Linking it to a certain view controller within the Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, xib

I have an action that I need to have linked to a certain view in the Storyboard. The code I currently have below links to the Storyboard's first view. How would I link it to a certain view controller within the Storyboard? FYI - this link is coming from a xib file that's not part of the Storyboard and it works fine. thanks

```
  - (IBAction)continueWithoutLoginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender 
    {

        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController* initialHelpView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        initialHelpView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentModalViewController:initialHelpView animated:YES];
    }
```

I'm wondering if the method: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: and then identifying one of the views in the storyboard would work.

```
 - (IBAction)continueWithoutLoginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender 
{

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   // UIViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RotationVC"];

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the method: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: and then identifying one of the views in the storyboard:

```
 - (IBAction)continueWithoutLoginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender 
{

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   // UIViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RotationVC"];

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```